# Java Completable future code optimisation

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a service class that read a list of words  from a csv file and search them in a folder with couple thousand of xml files. It should be able to match the existing words in each xml files in about 30s but mine takes lot of minutes. I tried to optimize changind data structures and playing with exceutors but did not performs much better. Do you think I can do some better for the compleatable futures? Or maybe the xml reading can be optimised?

```
@Service
public class XmlSearchService {

private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(XmlSearchService.class);

private final CsvParser csvParser;
private final Printer printer;

public XmlSearchService(CsvParser csvParser, Printer printer) {
    this.csvParser = csvParser;
    this.printer = printer;
}

public void searchInXmlFiles(String folderPath, String csvFilePath) {
    try {
        StopWatch timeMeasure = new StopWatch();
        timeMeasure.start("Task 1");
        int parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallelism);

        Set<String> companyNames = csvParser.parseCompanyNames(csvFilePath);
        List<Path> xmlFiles = getXmlFiles(folderPath);

        List<CompletableFuture<List<String>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

   /*     List<List<Path> > lists = Lists.partition(xmlFiles, 2);
        List<Path> xmlFiles1 = lists.get(1);

        for (List<Path> sublist: lists)
            System.out.println(sublist);*/


        for (Path xmlFile : xmlFiles) {
            CompletableFuture<List<String>> future = CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(() -> {

                        return searchInXmlFile(xmlFile, companyNames);

                    },executor);

            futures.add(future);
        }

        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]));
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> combinedFuture = allFutures.thenApply(v ->
                futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        );

        List<String> searchResults = combinedFuture.get();
        timeMeasure.stop();

        printer.print(searchResults);
        System.out.println("Last task time in Sec: " + timeMeasure.getTotalTimeSeconds());
        executor.shutdown();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
static void executionThread(){
    System.out.println("Thread execution - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}



private List<Path> getXmlFiles(String folderPath) throws IOException {
    return Files.walk(Paths.get(folderPath))
            .parallel()
            .filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".xml"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}





private List<String> searchInXmlFile(Path xmlFile, Set<String> companyNames) {
    try {
        System.out.println(xmlFile);
        Set<String> xmlWords = new HashSet<>();
        String xmlContent = Files.readString(xmlFile);
        String[] words = xmlContent.split("\\s+"); // Split the XML content into words
        xmlWords.addAll(Arrays.asList(words)); // Add the words to the HashSet

        return companyNames.stream()
                .filter(companyName -> isCompanyMentioned(xmlWords, companyName))
                .map(companyName -> xmlFile.getFileName() + ": " + companyName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //logger.error("Error occurred while processing XML file {}: {}", xmlFile, e.getMessage());
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}



private boolean isCompanyMentioned(Set<String> xmlWords, String companyName) {
    return xmlWords.stream()
            .anyMatch(word -> word.equalsIgnoreCase(companyName));
}


}
```

Comment: "It should be able to match the existing words in each xml files in about 30s". Can you verify this, by adding some time measurement to the `searchInXmlFile` method?

Comment: Yes I did, and it takes minutes

Comment: How many minutes? Please be specific in questions. "A lot" is not a number.

Comment: 60 mins less or more

Comment: “tried to optimize changing data structures”—that’s Cargo Cult programming. Using a `Set` doesn’t optimize anything if you keep iterating over the set instead of using its efficient lookup method. You even nest two iterations over sets, getting quadratic time complexity. Plus everything else one can do wrong 1) reading the entire file into memory, into a giant string, 2) splitting the entire file into a big array of strings, 3) copying the entire array into a `HashSet` for no benefit. 4) Not using an XML parser to process XML files…